# How to use jest to mock the results being sent back in the callback functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

Is there a way to mock the `storage` object so I can control the `err` and `v` passed back in the callback function when I do `storage.get`?

```
const mod = (() => {
  let value;

  return {
    init: (storage) => {
      storage.get('key', (err, v) => {
        value = v;
      });
    },
    get: () => value
  };
})();
```

Since I care about the side effects of `storage.get` I cannot simply do `mockImplementation` to override the function. is that correct?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *test* here? mod? If so then you provide storage by calling the init method on the object you returns, so you can pass any test double you like.

Comment: yes I am testing mod. but mod has a side effect when I do `storage.get` it assign local variables `value`. And I want to test after I `init` the module I can `get` the value correctly.

Comment: Oh you're right. I can just create a proper `storage` and pass it in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a mocked `storage` object and pass it into `mod.init` method.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
const mod = (() => {
  let value;

  return {
    init: (storage) => {
      storage.get('key', (err, v) => {
        value = v;
      });
    },
    get: () => value,
  };
})();

export { mod };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { mod } from './';

describe('63640360', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mStorage = {
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((key, callback) => {
        callback(null, 'teresa teng');
      }),
    };
    mod.init(mStorage);
    const actual = mod.get();
    expect(actual).toBe('teresa teng');
    expect(mStorage.get).toBeCalledWith('key', expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63640360/index.test.ts
  63640360
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.079s, estimated 9s
```